# Dart Function not inputting Variables

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm creating a Dart Function to use repeatedly across my app. its 2 buttons linked to a counter locally (localCounter, it's between the 2 buttons) as well as linked to a counter that catches all the button presses across the app (GlobalCuonter) when I input the the integers directly into the code, it works fine but when I use the it as a function, and make it so i can input the variables, it doesn't seem to work but i'm also not getting any errors in the code.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    const MyApp(),
  );
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
        body: SafeArea(
          child: MainPage(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MainPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MainPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MainPage> createState() => _MainPageState();
}

class _MainPageState extends State<MainPage> {
int TP1LeftCounter = 0;                                      //localCounter
int movpLeftCounter = 0;                                     //globalCounter


Row TpScores(int localCounter, int globalCounter) {          //Dart Function I'm trying to create
  return Row(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
    children: [
      ClipRRect(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
        child: InkWell(
          onTap: () {
            setState(() {
              if (localCounter > 0) localCounter--;
              if (globalCounter > 0) globalCounter--;
            });
          },
          child: Container(
            child: Icon(Icons.remove, color: Colors.white),
            width: 25.0,
            height: 35.0,
            color: Colors.blueGrey[900],
          ),
        ),
      ),
      Container(
        child: Text(
          '$localCounter',
          style: TextStyle(
            fontFamily: 'SourceSansPro',
            fontSize: 40.0,
            color: Colors.white,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      ClipRRect(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
        child: InkWell(
          onTap: () {
            setState(() {
              if (localCounter < 12) localCounter++;
              if (globalCounter < 12) globalCounter++;
            });
          },
          child: Container(
            child: Icon(Icons.add, color: Colors.white),
            width: 25.0,
            height: 35.0,
            color: Colors.blueGrey[900],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ],
  );
}

A
```

nd then in my build i put:

```
Expanded(
  child: Container(
    height: 50.0,
    child: TpScores(TP1LeftCounter, movpLeftCounter),
  ),
),
```

the counters don't tick up or down but the buttons are working.

am I missing something? cheers

Answer (score 0):

It's because the value is copied, you're not incrementing `TP1LeftCounter` and `movpLeftCounter` but `localCounter` and `globalCounter`

You should increment `TP1LeftCounter`, `movpLeftCounter` in the setState method.

Example

```
void main() {
  var v1 = 0;
  
  void incr(int value) {
    value++;
    print('value is $value');
    print('v1 is $v1');
  }
  
  incr(v1);
}
```

Will output

```
value is 1
v1 is 0
```